# Navigate from a controller to another controller having a root controller between them

Tags: swift

I have 3 controllers: RootController, FirstController and SecondController.
I want to navigate from RootController -> FirstController (here I press a button) -> Take me to SecondController.
How can I do this without Notifications and Observers and without to create a segue from that button to SecondVC because after I need to press < Back and again < Back.

This is what I've tried to do but is not working:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func goToSecondVC(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Go from first VC to second VC

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let showSecondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "goSecondVC") as! SecondViewController
        self.present(showSecondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: The root view controller is the one in charge of the navigation so instead of trying to present inside the first view controller (or the second) they are going to tell the root controller to do it.  One solution would be to use a delegate on the first/second view controllers that you assign to the root view controller so that they can execute a method on the delegate which the root view controller uses to switch controllers.

Comment: And how can I do this more exactly ? Also I take in consideration to do it also with Observers because seems to be impossible without a design pattern.

Comment: One problem is because you are wanting to go back up the navigation chain and then back down to the second view controller it will not look good visually.  In my test you briefly see the root view controller before it goes to the second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For your code example to work your SecondViewController needs to have the Storyboard ID set to "goSecondVC". This is done in the Identity inspector in the third tab in the right pane. This will present your ViewController modally. However since you have a navigationController you most likely want to push the SecondViewController on the navigationStack like so:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks Jakob, but with this solution I need to click 2 times <Back to go on the RootVC. Is the same if I create a segue from the Button to SecondVC. This is why I need to do it somehow different.

Comment: Oh, in that case you need to set the ViewControllers property: navigationController?.setViewControllers([secondVC], animated: true)
This way you will only have one ViewController in the stack